# export arabic rdlc report to MSWord

Tags: rdlc

After export the rdlc report to MS Word the arabic text appear from left to right.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the properties of the the table and the 
textbox

```
Direction=RTL
LayoutDirection=RTL
```